# JQuery - "Selector" for current position in document

Tags: jquery

Is there a selector or function in JQuery that allows to select the "current position in the document"?

For example if I use

```
<script>document.write("test");</script>
```

the output will be placed in the HTML document at the "position" where this "code" stands. But jQuery always requires a special selector. Of course I could be using a "marker div" with a unique selector, but is it also possible to insert HTML with JQuery right at the place where where the JQuery expression stands?

I tried

```
<script>$(this).after("test");</script>
```

but this it's not working. Help would be very much appreciated how this can be solved. Thank you!

EDIT:

Regarding the question below: The Idea is not to directly print out something with `document.writeln` (it was more meant as an example) but to determine the current "position" in the document with jQuery (and than starting from that position on with "navigation/traversal" of elements by using the jQuery functionality.

Maybe this can be called a "relative traversal of elements starting from the current position on in the DOM Tree"?

```
<div>Position1</div>
<div>Position2</div>
<script> HOW TO GET THIS POSITION WITH JQUERY (SEE NOTES BELOW) TO FURTHER NAVIGATE FROM HERE ON (RELATIVELY) TO THE PREVIOUS OR NEXT ELEMENT</script>
<div>Position3</div>
<div>Position4</div>
```

NOTES: The script tag with the jQuery statements will be inserted dynamically in the document and what I am interested in is, to be able to navigate from this position on in the document with jQuery. In the script Tag I might call something like "WRAP THE NEXT HTML ELEMENT WITH A TAG VIA JQUERY" or "GIVE ME THE NEXT HTML ELEMENTS VALUE-ATTRIBUTE". As stated above it is possible to insert a "marker div" to determine the position but the question is, if JQuery is "autonomically" able to determine it's position in the DOM-Tree (to start navigation in a "relative manner" from there on).

Comment: Why not just add classes to your divs so you have some selectors to use find the one you wanted?  <div class="current">Position2</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$("script:last") seems to work for all modern browsers (except IE)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write($("script:last").text());
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("---");
    document.write($("script:last").text());
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I used `$('script:first').attr('id)` and it got me the id of the script the code was run in. Might help!

Comment: Scratch that! I used `$('script:first').text()` and it got me the text of the script, but for some curious reason `$('script:first').attr('id')` didn't get me it's id.

Comment: Be aware of some potential problems if You have browser extensions installed. For example some of my chrome extensions added scripts to the page ("lastpass" for example), so $("script:last") was not current script but added by lastpass

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that right, you want a feature doing exactly the same as document.write, I don't understand why you want that and not just use document.write then?

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question and tried to clarify this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's easy: just give an id attribute to your inline script tag:

```
  <script id="hello">alert("hello");</script>
```

then you can just do :

```
$('script#hello').after('<span style="color:red">this is my new content</span>');
```

**UPDATE:**

since you don't want to modify the html markup, then the only alternative is to access your script tags according to their order of appearance in the code.

```
  $('script').each(function(index){
// "index" gives you the instance number, which you could use, for example inside a switch case.
switch(index){
case '1':
    $(this).after('<span style="color:red">i am number 1</span>');
break;

case '2':
    $(this).after('<span style="color:red">i am number 2</span>');
break;

default:
    $(this).after('<span style="color:red">i am number '+index+'</span>');
break;
}
    });
```

or you can access a specific one via .eq(index) :

```
$('script').eq(2).after('hello world');  
// this is for the third script tag, starting from the top of the document.
```

Comment: hellp Pixeline. Thank you very much for your answer. Well I like your solution, but in the end its the same as using a merker div (only that it saves the div...) The Problem with this approach is once again (like the div solution) that I need to generate/assign a unique ID attribute to the script tag. The goal is however to have an "unaltered/blank script tag" placed multiple times in the code. And this would not be working with your solution. thanks markus

Comment: i've updated my answer according to your need. Can't do much better than that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a solution using jQuery, but you can find out the DOM node in the current caret position in most browsers quite easily using:

- document.selection.createRange() in IE (see MSDN)
- window.getSelection().focusNode in most other browsers (Gecko et al, see [MDC Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection))

Good luck!

Comment: this question is not about the caret position.

it is about which script tag the browser is executing javascript from